# How to resolve two jquery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page which includes jquery for curtain effects and other for slider.the problem i am facing is my both jqueries are not working together.what should i do?

my sample code is

```
    <!-- for slider -->
<script src="images/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="images/jquery.bxslider2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="images/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- for curtain -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you need to add jQuery twice?

Comment: Note: JavaScript != Java (tags)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, try using the [current jQuery version (1.7.2)](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js) and see if both scripts work.

If not, consider using something that is compatible with the current jQuery version - if something requires jquery 1.3 it wasn't updated for a long time.

If you really need both scripts and both requires different jQuery versions, then you'll need to do it like this:

```
<script src=".../jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="script-that-needs-132.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src=".../jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

To use the old jQuery, then wrap the code, using it, like this:

```
(function($){
    // here $ points to the old jQuery
})(jQuery132);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove one of them, preferably this one `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, removing the second one should do it. Also as a side note, why are you placing your jquery inside a directory called images?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't include two different versions of jQuery. Stick to one (the most recent one should be the best choice). If your desired plugin does only support a very ancient version like 1.3 is, then you should choose a more recent one or start fiddling around in the code.