# How to add jquery in perfex crm?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crm

Every time i try to add jquery using cdn links or even loading it from the assets in my module,
it will conflict with the perfex crm default jquery.
what should i do ?

i tried adding jquery in my module like this :

```php
 hooks()->add_filter('before_compile_css_assets',function(){
   // include 'assets/jquery.js';
   echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js' ></script>";
  });

// or like this 

 hooks()->add_filter('before_compile_scripts_assets',function(){
   // include 'assets/jquery.js';
   echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js' ></script>";
  });
```

Comment: If it's conflicting with a version of jQuery that's already there, maybe the answer is to use the one that's already there and not load another. Otherwise, there is a noConflict flag - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978770/how-to-resolve-two-jquery-conflict

Comment: @Jerry the weird part is that i can't use jquery in my app. and also i tried the link u send me and still nothing changed

Comment: @Jerry also a side note : i get this error when i add jquery cdn with the code i posted : Uncaught TypeError: "$" is read-only

Comment: Try using `jQuery` rather than `$` in your code. IIRC (it's been a while) but I think the conflict between jQuery versions is about which version gets to define `$` - which is just a convenience.

Comment: @Jerry i tried Using JQuery instead of $ but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

**let's assume that my module name is  woocommerce**

```
//for app admin footer (if you want to add in footer)
        hooks()->add_action('app_admin_footer', 'woocommerce_load_js');
        function woocommerce_load_js()
        {
            echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js' ></script>";
        }

// for app admin head (if you want to add in header)
    hooks()->add_action('app_admin_head', 'woocommerce_load_js');
    function woocommerce_load_js()
    {
        echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js' ></script>";
    }
```

**now after adding jquery you can using code like this**

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});
</script>
```